# Taking input through methods and GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, file-io, methods

So, I have an assignment that covers a lot. I need to:

- Have a GUI with two buttons on the bottom. Both buttons grab a separate file from my temp folder.
- I have to use a method we used in the past (collectGrades and averageGrade) and output that data to the text field box in the middle when clicking the second button

**I need to take the data from the studentscores.txt (which is an int field, and a double field) and put them into a StringBuilder and then output the stringBuilder onto the jTextframe.**

```
private void jbtReadFileActionPerformed2(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        File inFile = new File("c:/temp/studentscores.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
        String fileContents = "";
        while(input.hasNext()) {
        students.add(new Student(input.nextInt(),input.nextLine()));

    } // end while

    for(int o = 0;o < students.size();o++) {
    students.get(o).setGrades(collectGrades(students.get(o).getStuId()));   

    jtxtAfileContents.setText("%-10d %-20s %.2f\n", students.get(o).getStuId(),     students.get(o).getStuName(), averageGrade(students.get(o).getGrades())););
```

How do I get this to work?

```
import java.awt.*        
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;     
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class P_Supplemental_11 extends JFrame {

    JPanel jpnl1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton jbtReadFile1 = new JButton("Get Student Names");
    JButton jbtReadFile2 = new JButton("Get Student Grades");
    JTextField jtxtFilePath = new JTextField();
    JLabel jlblDesc = new JLabel("Click a button to open each file!");
    JTextArea jtxtAfileContents = new JTextArea();


    P_Supplemental_11() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 10));
    jpnl1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    jpnl1.add(jlblDesc);
    //jpnl1.add(jtxtFilePath);
    southPanel.add(jbtReadFile1);
    southPanel.add(jbtReadFile2);
    add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(jpnl1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(jtxtAfileContents, BorderLayout.CENTER);







    jbtReadFile1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

         jbtReadFileActionPerformed(evt);
     }

    });


    jbtReadFile2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

         jbtReadFileActionPerformed2(evt);
     }

    });


    } // end constructor

    class Student {
    private int stuId;
    private String stuName;
    private ArrayList<Double> grades;

    Student(int idIn, String nameIn) {

        this.stuId = idIn;
        this.stuName = nameIn;
       } // end student class


        public int getStuId() {
            return stuId;
        }


        public void setStuId(int stuId) {
            this.stuId = stuId;
        }

         String getStuName() {
            return stuName;
        }


        public void setStuName(String stuName) {
            this.stuName = stuName;
        }


        public ArrayList<Double> getGrades() {
            return grades;
        }


        public void setGrades(ArrayList grades) {
            this.grades = grades;
        }



   } // end class Student

    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList();

    private void jbtReadFileActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        File inFile = new File("c:/temp/studentnames.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
        String fileContents = "";
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            fileContents+= input.nextLine() + "\n";
        } // end while

        jtxtAfileContents.setText(fileContents);
        input.close();

    } // end action method for jbtReadFile button
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(P_Supplemental_11.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   }

   private void jbtReadFileActionPerformed2(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        File inFile = new File("c:/temp/studentscores.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
        String fileContents = "";
        while(input.hasNext()) {
        students.add(new Student(input.nextInt(),input.nextLine()));

    } // end while

    for(int o = 0;o < students.size();o++) {
    students.get(o).setGrades(collectGrades(students.get(o).getStuId()));   

    jtxtAfileContents.setText("%-10d %-20s %.2f\n", students.get(o).getStuId(),     students.get(o).getStuName(), averageGrade(students.get(o).getGrades())););

        /*String fileContents = "";
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            fileContents+= input.nextLine() + "\n";
        } // end while
        input.close();
        jtxtAfileContents.setText(collectGrades.getStuName);
        */


    }
    } // end action method for jbtReadFile button
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(P_Supplemental_11.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


public static ArrayList <Double> collectGrades(int inId) {

    ArrayList <Double> outGrade = new ArrayList();
    try {
        File inFile = new File("c:/temp/studentScores.txt");
           Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
           while(input.hasNext()) {
           int tmpInt = input.nextInt();
           double tmpDbl = input.nextDouble();
           if(tmpInt == inId) {
               outGrade.add(tmpDbl);
           } // end if
           } // end while

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(P_Supplemental_11.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } // end catch

    return outGrade;
} // end method

public static double averageGrade(ArrayList <Double> gradeIn) {
    double outAvg = 0.0;

    for(int y = 0; y < gradeIn.size();y++) {
    outAvg+= gradeIn.get(y);
} // end for

return outAvg/gradeIn.size();

}





public static void main(String[] args) {
    P_Supplemental_11 frame = new P_Supplemental_11();
    frame.setTitle("P_Supplemenetal_10");
    frame.setSize(410, 520);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

} // end main
} // end public class P_Supp_11
```

Comment: There's too much code here and not enough specificity of where you think the error is. Try to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: What exactly is not working for you. Plz be more specific :)

Comment: I edited the file at the top with the specific question and code.

Comment: It's not the answer but there is a semicolon missing in your first line.

Comment: Can you give an example of the file formats and an explanation of what's not working, please

Comment: The files are text files. ONe called studentNames with an ID field matching the student name. The other file is called studentGrades.text and it is an ID field with grades

Answer (score 2):

I put your code so that it runs, is that what you meant?

[image: Press the button]

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Student extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Splashing");
                StudentView view = new StudentView();
                frame.getContentPane().add(view);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 450));
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static class StudentView extends JPanel {
        JPanel jpnl1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton jbtReadFile1 = new JButton("Get Student Names");
        JButton jbtReadFile2 = new JButton("Get Student Grades");
        JTextField jtxtFilePath = new JTextField();
        JLabel jlblDesc = new JLabel("Click a button to open each file!");
        JTextArea jtxtAfileContents = new JTextArea();

        StudentView() {
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 10));
            jpnl1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
            jpnl1.add(jlblDesc);
            //jpnl1.add(jtxtFilePath);
            jbtReadFile2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            jtxtAfileContents.setText(collectGrades());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            southPanel.add(jbtReadFile1);
            southPanel.add(jbtReadFile2);
            add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(jpnl1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(jtxtAfileContents, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        private String collectGrades() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Hello World");
            builder.append("More info");
            return builder.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the GUI done - I just need to be able to click "Get Student Grades" and it parse through my collectGrades method and pass that back to the output in the center.

Comment: So you have added an actionListner to your `jbtReadFile2`? This should call a method that reads from the file. Thhis input you then pass to `collectGrades` which then updates `jtxtAfileContents`. Which part does not work?

Comment: Well, we updated the assignment. This is an extension of another assignment - any way we can chat about this so I can explain more in depth?

Comment: Basically, I have a collectGrades method that takes the ID from the first file and matches it to the ID Field in the second file. If the ID's match, we add a double grade to it. When I click the second button, I need that method to run and then output the data to a Stringbuilder.

Comment: When you click the 2nd button the `collectGrades` will run and update the `TextArea`.

Comment: My collectGrades method passes an int value

Comment: I still have not understood the problem. Sorry, I don't have any more time. Good luck.